# How to use AVPlayer addBoundaryTimeObserver?

Tags: swift, avplayer

I am recording the beat count of a song manually, by tapping on a button in the UI.

After that, I want to play the song again call `addBoundaryTimeObserver` every time the keys of arrayOfBeats match the `playerItem.currentTime`

How can I feed the keys of `arrayOfBeats`  to `addBoundaryTimeObserver` method?

```
   //save the time as a string with 2 decimal places
  let timeString = String(format: "%.2f", strongSelf.timeInSeconds)

 let arrayOfBeats = ["2.18": 3, "3.38": 5, "3.63": 6] // x.y seconds : beatCount
 var timeObserverToken:Any!

   func addBoundaryTimeObserver(url: URL) {

    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
    player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)

  // Build boundary times from arrayOfBeats keys
    let keys = arrayOfBeats.keys.compactMap {$0}

    // how can I convert keys to to NSValue as in  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1388027-addboundarytimeobserver

   var times = [NSValue]()
   let mainQueue = DispatchQueue.main
   player?.play()

   timeObserverToken =
        player?.addBoundaryTimeObserver(forTimes: times, queue: mainQueue) {
        //update label with beatCount every time duration of audio file is transversed and it matches an element in  var times = [NSValue]()
  }
}//end addBoundaryTimeObserver
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the docs

> **times** - An array of NSValue objects containing `CMTime` values representing the times at which to invoke block.

You need to create appropriate `CMTime` structs then create an array of `NSValue` objects:

```
let cmtime = CMTime(seconds: 2.18, preferredTimescale: 100)
let cmtimevalue = NSValue(time: cmtime)
let cmtimevalueArray = [cmtimevalue]
```

Be aware that the seconds for this initialiser is `Double` and `timescale` is `CMTimeScale` aka `Int32`

Also your `arrayOfBeats` is not an `Array`, it's a `Dictionary` and items in dictionaries are NOT ordered. You probably won't get the order you were looking for.

You might be better served with an array of tuples.

```
let arrayOfBeats = [("2.18", 3), ("3.38", 5), ("3.63", 6)]
```

Converting your `String` seconds value back to `Double` is your (trivial) problem.

Comment: is there any reason why you wrote `preferredTimescale: 3`. Based on criteria should I choose the value of  preferredTimescale? Many thanks

Comment: Thats from your supplied dataset of  `("2.18", 3)`  Im unsure how the actual value you input into the `init` relates your beat-count. The other `CMTime` initialisers use `Int64` as the seconds value so you would have to scale the `Double` by something maybe by x1000. Your question was how to create the `[NSValue]` array. The actual data is your problem :-)

Comment: I looked up the API. second arg is resolution. So you'd multiply by your `timescale` to get the correct `seconds` value for the other init.

Comment: For `preferredTimescale` it's better to use `CMTimeScale.(NSEC_PER_SEC)`